.offerCodeRedemption sheet's 'Open App' button doesn't work
I'm opening offer code sheet using .offerCodeRedemption(isPresented:) in my app.
When user successfully redeems an offer code he sees the screenshot below.
The issue is that when user taps "Open App" button, nothing happens.
I understand that this is Apple's sheet and we can't control it, but our users still having issue with this.

The only idea I had is to use init with completion, to manually close the sheet, when a code is successfuly used, but this doesn't seems to work either. I'm not sure if it doesn't work because I test it in Xcode or in general.
Code I tried:
.offerCodeRedemption(isPresented: $isRedeemPromocodePresented) { result in
    switch result {
        case .success:
            isRedeemPromocodePresented = false
        case .failure:
            isRedeemPromocodePresented = false
    }
}


I'm also seeing the same issue in my app. Hopefully someone knows of a solution
